# Complex MySQL not returning the results I need

Tags: mysql

tl:dr
I am needing to take the most recent row per employee from one table and match it to multiple rows per employee from another table.  I am able to get the most recent entry per employee from the one table, but cannot pull the data from the second table.

Details:

The first two tables show some representative data from my database.  The data and tables shown here are snippets of my full schema and data set.
(TABLES: 'employees' and 'employee_payrollhours')

employee_number:    this is an ID number to ID  the individual employee
inserted_at:        This is a date/time stamp when the record was saved to the database
datetime_in:        This is the date/time when the employee started his shift

```
SELECT employee_number, last_name, inserted_at FROM employees;
TABLE:  employees
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| employee_number |  last_name  | inserted_at         |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
|       123456789 | Lastone     | 2018-02-26 22:26:38 |
|       123456789 | Lastone     | 2018-03-15 15:16:14 |
|       123456789 | Lastone     | 2018-03-15 20:57:23 |
|       123456789 | Lastone     | 2018-04-16 00:10:27 |
|       223456789 | Lasttwo     | 2018-04-16 03:37:49 |
|       270000001 | Lastthree   | 2018-04-06 22:42:50 |
|       270000001 | Lastthree   | 2018-04-17 14:10:01 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+


SELECT employee_number, datetime_in FROM employee_payrollhours
TABLE:  employee_payrollhours
+-----------------+---------------------+
| employee_number | datetime_in         |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|       123456789 | 2018-04-06 08:00:00 |
|       123456789 | 2018-04-08 08:00:00 |
|       123456789 | 2018-04-10 08:00:00 |
|       123456789 | 2018-04-15 08:00:00 |
|       123456789 | 2018-04-17 08:00:00 |
|       123456789 | 2018-04-19 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-06 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-08 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-10 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-15 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-17 08:00:00 |
|       223456789 | 2018-04-19 08:00:00 |
|       270000001 | 2018-04-07 08:00:00 |
|       270000001 | 2018-04-09 08:00:00 |
|       270000001 | 2018-04-11 08:00:00 |
|       270000001 | 2018-04-16 08:00:00 |
+-----------------+---------------------+
```

To get one row for each employee from the employees

```
SELECT * FROM employees GROUP BY last_name
```

and to get the most recent entry for each employee from the employees table.

```
SELECT * FROM employees e1
WHERE Inserted_at = 
    (SELECT MAX(e2.Inserted_at)
    FROM employees e2
    WHERE e1.Employee_Number = e2.Employee_Number)
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
| employee_number |  last_name  | inserted_at         |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
|       123456789 | Lastone     | 2018-04-16 00:10:27 |
|       223456789 | Lasttwo     | 2018-04-16 03:37:49 |
|       270000001 | Lastthree   | 2018-04-17 14:10:01 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

This is what I want.  I want the most recent entry for each employee from 'employees' displayed with the corresponding employee data from the 'employee_payrollhours' table.

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
|     last_name     | datetime_in         |
+-------------------+---------------------+
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-06 08:00:00 |
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-08 08:00:00 |
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-10 08:00:00 |
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-15 08:00:00 |
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-17 08:00:00 |
|       Lastone     | 2018-04-19 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-06 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-08 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-10 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-15 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-17 08:00:00 |
|       Lasttwo     | 2018-04-19 08:00:00 |
|       Lastthree   | 2018-04-07 08:00:00 |
|       Lastthree   | 2018-04-09 08:00:00 |
|       Lastthree   | 2018-04-11 08:00:00 |
|       Lastthree   | 2018-04-16 08:00:00 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

This query gives me the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
SELECT employees.*, employee_payrollhours.*
FROM employees, employee_payrollhours
WHERE employee_payrollhours.employee_number = (select employee_number from employees group by last_name);
```

This query gives me mixed up data.

```
SELECT employees.last_name, employees.employee_number, employee_payrollhours.employee_number, employee_payrollhours.datetime_in
FROM employees, employee_payrollhours
WHERE employee_payrollhours.employee_number = employees.employee_number;
```

and this query gives me zero returned results

```
SELECT * FROM employees e1, employee_payrollhours
WHERE `e1`.`Inserted_at` = 
    (SELECT MAX(e2.Inserted_at)
    FROM employees e2
    WHERE e1.Employee_Number = e2.Employee_Number)
    AND (`e1`.`Inserted_at` = 
    (SELECT MAX(e2.Inserted_at)
    FROM employees e2
    WHERE e1.Employee_Number = e2.Employee_Number)) = employee_payrollhours.Employee_Number;
```

Would someone please give me some direction on how to approach this problem to find the query I need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are of course many ways to do it, and I'm going to present only one of them. The trick here is getting the last entry by `inserted_at` from the `employees` table. One way to do it is of course do a `group by` query with `max`, but then we won't be able to join the `employee_payrollhours` table. However, we can use a trick were we do a `left outer join` of `employees` on itself using as condition having a bigger `inserted_at` and then filter only the record in which the join is null which will give us the same result of a `group by` query but we'll still be allowed to join the `employee_payrollhours` and get the wanted result.

Like this:

```
select e1.*, eprh.* from employees e1
  left outer join employees e2 on
    e1.employee_number = e2.employee_number and
    e2.inserted_at > e1.inserted_at
  left join employees_payrollhours eprh on
    eprh.employee_number = e1.employee_number
where e2.employee_number is null
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I've put this code into my PHP code and have the correct results returned, assuming I'm not overlooking something.  Both solutions given up to this point worked excellently.  The only reason I chose this solution over the other was this one displayed employees with "null" time entered, which would allow our part-time employees be displayed even if they did not have any hours recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fd5c8/1)) will do what you want:

```
select e.last_name, e.most_recent, p.datetime_in
from (select employee_number, last_name, max(inserted_at) as most_recent from employees group by employee_number) e
left join employee_payrollhours p
on p.employee_number = e.employee_number
```

Output:

```
last_name   most_recent             datetime_in
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-06 08:00:00
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-08 08:00:00
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-10 08:00:00
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-15 08:00:00
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-17 08:00:00
Lastone     2018-04-16 00:10:27     2018-04-19 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-06 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-08 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-10 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-15 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-17 08:00:00
Lasttwo     2018-04-16 03:37:49     2018-04-19 08:00:00
Lastthree   2018-04-17 14:10:01     2018-04-07 08:00:00
Lastthree   2018-04-17 14:10:01     2018-04-09 08:00:00
Lastthree   2018-04-17 14:10:01     2018-04-11 08:00:00
Lastthree   2018-04-17 14:10:01     2018-04-16 08:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay.  I really appreciate the work you put into this, especially with the fiddle with the data and solution shown.  This solution gave me the results I had asked for, but there was one condition that I had not really considered.  The other solution covered that condition, whereas this one didn't.  This solution may very well be something that someone else needs, however.

Comment: Had you included that condition I would have given a different answer, It's a simple matter of changing `join` to `left join`. I have edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: I'm sure you would have.  And you are correct, it was not listed in my original post.  That is definitely on me.  When I was writing the post, I did not think about that situation.  My apologies to you.  For what it is worth, I did give you both +1's.  Unfortunately, my rep is still too low for my +1's to show.

Comment: Not a problem Jim, I've done the same thing myself. And thanks for the +1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both (upto the time of this writing) for the very prompt replies.  I obviously need a lot more MySQL practice.

In the comments, I explained why I chose the answer I did.

I tried both solutions in my application.  The one I chose allowed those employees who had not entered any time to still be displayed.  This covers the part-time employees who may not have worked during a particular time period to still be displayed in the results.